# Add argument off function to string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, arguments

I want to add an argument of a function to a string (iam not sure if thats the right word)

```
function changeChart(form, chart, bar) {

            //chart 2 (left)
            $(form).change(function (){

                console.log(form);

                $(form + "option:selected").each(function(){
                //rest of the function
```

I want the form added to the selection in Jquery.

Is this the right way?

Comment: Are you having trouble doing this?

Comment: What does `form` look like? Is it the `actual object`, such as `$('#myForm')`, or is it a string representation of the selector, such as `#myForm`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `form` is a string, you need to be sure there's a space before `"option:selected"`.

```
$(form + " option:selected").each(function(){
```

---

If `form` is an element, pass it to the jQuery functin, then use `find`:

```
$(form).find("option:selected").each(function(){
```

Or use the context parameter *(though IMO the code is less clear)*:

```
$("option:selected", form).each(function(){
```

---

Although, since you're in the handler, you could just use `this` to reference the form element.

```
$(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
```

Comment: `$(form).find("option:selected")` should be `$('option:selected', form)` in this scenario.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: I added that, but why do you say it "should be"? It's a little less efficient to add `form` as the context.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - does'nt matter, the latter is just a shortcut for the former. On the other hand inside the function it would be better to use `this` in the context .

Answer (score 0):

If form is a string that corresponds to an **ID**

Then it's supposed to be

```
$('#' + form)

$('#' + form + " option:selected")
```

If its a class replace **#** with a **.**